# PHP array only showing last item in for loop

Tags: php, json, xml

### What I am doing:

- Reading an XML recipe file and getting it's flavours (for simplicity I have included a snippet)
- Converting some of its data
- Creating multiple flavour arrays with keys (trying to)
- `json_encode`(ing) the arrays and inserting into a `MySQL DB` (code not included as not important)

### The Problem & Question

I am only seeing the last item from each XML recipe in each array. Can you see what I'm doing wrong here?

#### Output:

```
Array
(
    [flavourcompany] => Flavor West
    [flavourname] => Yellow Cake
    [flavourpercent] => 1.00
)
Array
(
    [flavourcompany] => Flavour Art
    [flavourname] => Honey (Miele)
    [flavourpercent] => 0.75
)
```

### The code

```
$xmldata = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="#" ?>
<recipes>
<recipe><name><![CDATA[Bronuts]]></name><pg_vg_goal>30/70</pg_vg_goal><created_at>2016-09-29 07:48:40</created_at><url>http://tjek.nu/r/7eHn</url><flavors><flavor><name>Chocolate Glazed Doughnut (Cap)</name><percentage>7.00</percentage></flavor><flavor><name>Biscuit (Inawera)</name><percentage>0.75</percentage></flavor><flavor><name>Joy (FA)</name><percentage>0.75</percentage></flavor><flavor><name>Bavarian Cream (DX) (TPA)</name><percentage>2.00</percentage></flavor><flavor><name>Yellow Cake (FW)</name><percentage>1.00</percentage></flavor></flavors></recipe>
<recipe><name><![CDATA[Honeybee]]></name><pg_vg_goal>30/70</pg_vg_goal><created_at>2016-09-29 08:53:05</created_at><url>http://tjek.nu/r/7eJD</url><flavors><flavor><name>Cookie (Biscotto) (FA)</name><percentage>1.00</percentage></flavor><flavor><name>Marshmallow (FA)</name><percentage>2.00</percentage></flavor><flavor><name>Caramel (Caramello) (FA)</name><percentage>1.00</percentage></flavor><flavor><name>Cream Fresh (Panna Fresca) (FA)</name><percentage>2.00</percentage></flavor><flavor><name>Honey (Miele) (FA)</name><percentage>0.75</percentage></flavor></flavors></recipe></recipes>';

    $bom = simplexml_load_string($xmldata, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA | LIBXML_NOBLANKS);

    
    $json_string = json_encode($bom);
    $result_array = json_decode($json_string, TRUE);
    $numrecipes = count($result_array['recipe']);
            
    $flavourarray = array();
    
    
for($i = 0; $i < $numrecipes; $i++) {
    
    $recipeName = $result_array['recipe'][$i]['name'];
    $numflavours = count($result_array['recipe'][$i]['flavors']['flavor']);

    for($l = 0; $l < $numflavours; $l++) {
        
        
        $flavourName = $result_array['recipe'][$i]['flavors']['flavor'][$l]['name'];
        $flavourPercentage = $result_array['recipe'][$i]['flavors']['flavor'][$l]['percentage'];
        preg_match('/\(([A-Za-z\/]+)\)$/', $flavourName, $flavourCompanyabv);
        
        /**
            Replace company abbreviations with full company names
        */
        
        if(trim(strtolower($flavourCompanyabv[1])) == 'cap') {
            $flavourCompanyabv2 = 'Capella';
        }
        elseif(trim(strtolower($flavourCompanyabv[1])) == 'tpa') {
            $flavourCompanyabv2 = 'The Perfumers Apprentice';
        }
        elseif(trim(strtolower($flavourCompanyabv[1])) == 'fa') {
            $flavourCompanyabv2 = 'Flavour Art';
        }
        elseif(trim(strtolower($flavourCompanyabv[1])) == 'inawera' || trim(strtolower($flavourCompanyabv[1])) == 'inw') {
            $flavourCompanyabv2 = 'Inawera';
        }
        elseif(trim(strtolower($flavourCompanyabv[1])) == 'fw') {
            $flavourCompanyabv2 = 'Flavor West';
        }
        elseif(trim(strtolower($flavourCompanyabv[1])) == 'nn') {
            $flavourCompanyabv2 = 'Nude Nicotine';
        } else {
            $flavourCompanyabv2 = $flavourCompanyabv[1];
        }

        $flavourName2 = trim(preg_replace("/\(([A-Za-z\/]+)\)$/","",$flavourName));
        $flavourarray['flavourcompany'] = $flavourCompanyabv2;
        $flavourarray['flavourname'] = $flavourName2;
        $flavourarray['flavourpercent'] = $flavourPercentage;
        
    }
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($flavourarray);
        echo '</pre>';
        
}
```

#### The Expected Output:

```
Array
(
    [flavourCompany] => Capella
    [flavourName] => Chocolate Glazed Doughnut
    [flavourPercent] => 7.00
    [flavourCompany] => Inawera
    [flavourName] => Biscuit
    [flavourPercent] => 0.75
    [flavourCompany] => Flavour Art
    [flavourName] => Joy
    [flavourPercent] => 0.75
    [flavourCompany] => The Perfumers Apprentice
    [flavourName] => Bavarian Cream (DX)
    [flavourPercent] => 2.00
    [flavourCompany] => Flavor West
    [flavourName] => Yellow Cake
    [flavourPercent] => 1.00
)
Array
(
    [flavourCompany] => Capella
    [flavourName] => Chocolate Glazed Doughnut
    [flavourPercent] => 7.00
    [flavourCompany] => Inawera
    [flavourName] => Biscuit
    [flavourPercent] => 0.75
    [flavourCompany] => Flavour Art
    [flavourName] => Joy
    [flavourPercent] => 0.75
    [flavourCompany] => The Perfumers Apprentice
    [flavourName] => Bavarian Cream (DX)
    [flavourPercent] => 2.00
    [flavourCompany] => Flavor West
    [flavourName] => Yellow Cake
    [flavourPercent] => 1.00
    [flavourCompany] => Flavour Art
    [flavourName] => Cookie (Biscotto)
    [flavourPercent] => 1.00
    [flavourCompany] => Flavour Art
    [flavourName] => Marshmallow
    [flavourPercent] => 2.00
    [flavourCompany] => Flavour Art
    [flavourName] => Caramel (Caramello)
    [flavourPercent] => 1.00
    [flavourCompany] => Flavour Art
    [flavourName] => Cream Fresh (Panna Fresca)
    [flavourPercent] => 2.00
    [flavourCompany] => Flavour Art
    [flavourName] => Honey (Miele)
    [flavourPercent] => 0.75
)
```

Comment: Your expected output has multiple values for the same keys (i.e. flavourCompany), should these be separate sub arrays?

Comment: Ideally I would like the output as shown

Comment: Output as shown is impossible - each key in an array MUST be unique, or it will be overwritten. To circumvent this issue, you can use sub-arrays.

Comment: Ok, so how could I get the expected output but using sub arrays within the same array?

Comment: see answer below...

Comment: I would suggest not using the XML->JSON->array method, but this is probably beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Could you give me a brief idea of what you would do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of your loop, you just assign the values to the same elements of the end array...

```
    $flavourarray['flavourcompany'] = $flavourCompanyabv2;
    $flavourarray['flavourname'] = $flavourName2;
    $flavourarray['flavourpercent'] = $flavourPercentage;
```

these overwrite the previous values and you cannot have multiple items with the same key name.

Instead use something like...

```
    $flavourarray[] = ['flavourcompany' => $flavourCompanyabv2,
              'flavourname' => $flavourName2,
              'flavourpercent' => $flavourPercentage ];
```

which adds all of the items into a new element.

With your test data, this gives (abreviated)...

```
   [0] => Array
        (
            [flavourcompany] => Capella
            [flavourname] => Chocolate Glazed Doughnut
            [flavourpercent] => 7.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [flavourcompany] => Inawera
            [flavourname] => Biscuit
            [flavourpercent] => 0.75
        )
```

Comment: This is awesome and works great, I can accept in 4mins apparently :/ Thanks so much for your quick answer, you have saved me another 4 hours of frustration massive +1 to you :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP arrays have unique keys, so you have to build an array of arrays.
So, you have to change:

```
$flavourarray[] = [
    'flavourCompany' => $flavourCompanyabv2,
    'flavourName' => $flavourName2,
    'flavourPercent' => $flavourPercentage
];
```

The ouput:

```
    array(2) { 
        [0]=> array(3) { 
            ["flavourCompany"]=> string(7) "Capella" 
            ["flavourName"]=> string(25) "Chocolate Glazed Doughnut" 
            ["flavourPercent"]=> float(7) 
        } 
        [1]=> array(3) {
                ["flavourCompany"]=> string(7) "Inawera" 
                ["flavourName"]=> string(7) "Biscuit" 
                ["flavourPercent"]=> float(0.75) 
        } 
    }
```